# Wording of update prompt for game mods

Tags: games, alerts, updating, prompt

A friend of mine recently asked me a question regarding his UI on an update prompt for his mod update checker for Kerbal Space Program. He currently have two options: *An update is available:* `[Update]` and `[close]`.

He have got reports from users saying it is a bit obnoxious when it asks for the same updates every time they open the game, so he now wants to add an option to ignore an update entirely. /Do not prompt me again before a newer update is available)

I suggested `[ Update ]`, `[ Remind me later ]`, and `[ Ignore this update ]`.
 We figured `remind me later` and `ignore this update` had potential to be mixed up and misunderstood.

My question is whether you have any better fitting suggestions for the alert button labels, or a "standard alert action text"

[image]

Comment: The buttons seem OK to me: "Remind me later" = "I don't want to update now, but I might..." and "Ignore this update" = "I'm not interested in this update". However, I do find the "_Unsupported by..._" line and positioning (with it's different set of version numbers) a bit confusing (admittedly I know nothing of what KSP is).  If this is indicating that the underlying game (as opposed to mods for it) is out of date, then that might be better in either a separate dialog or in a separate section of this one (i.e. keep all the "mod update" stuff together and distinct from the "game update" stuff.

Comment: @TripeHound Please consider writing an answer. Comments are for question clarification or minor corrections.

Comment: Have done. It started off mainly as a "looks alright" comment that I didn't really feel warranted an answer. The bit about possible confusion occurred while I was typing and -- on reflection -- possibly does make it worth being an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The text of the buttons seems fairly clear:

<kbd>Remind me later</kbd> I don't want to take this update now , but I might want it later.

<kbd>Ignore this update</kbd> I'm not interested in this update; please don't ask me about it again.

However, I do find the "*Unsupported by...*" line a bit confusing: both by it's positioning – between the information about the *patch* update and the *Remind me*/*Ignore* buttons – and by the use of a different set of version numbers.

I am not familiar with KSP, and precisely what this message is trying to say; the two obvious meanings seem to be:

- The new patch (v1.1.3) will not work with the current version of KSP (v1.3.0) and you *must* update KSP to v1.3.1 before it will work.
- The current patch (v1.1.2) and/or the new one (v1.1.3) are *not guaranteed to work* with the current version of KSP (v1.3.0) and you are *recommended* to update KSP to v1.3.1.

In the first case (the new patch is known not to work with the older version of KSP), then I think you shouldn't be offering to download the new patch until the minimum version of KSP is in place, e.g.:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fuIDSN.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

In the second case, you want to separate the updating of the patch, from the recommendation of updating KSP, e.g.:

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYBgYp.png)</sup>

In either case, you may also want to consider adding a <kbd>?</kbd> icon (or similar), as I have above, which can display details about the new patch to help the user decide if they want to make use of it or not.